# Web-to-lead Creates Lead with Delay

Tags: leads, web2lead

I have a web-to-lead form.
I enabled the debugging as well to see what happens. When I submit the form it says Queued.
Why web-to-lead process queues the request? Even I have less than 500 per day. Is there a way around by which it can work to create lead immediately when the request submitted from the web form?

Thank you